# how to change variable value automatically in while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to control led lights based on its previous state using python code on my raspberry pi. Any suggestion how can I do it?

I have tried using checking gpio state using gpio.input() function, and changing variable value

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(35,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(35,GPIO.HIGH)

f = '1'

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    print "before"
    print f
    if f == '1':
        GPIO.output(35,GPIO.HIGH)
        f = '0'

    if f == '0':
        GPIO.output(35,GPIO.LOW)
        f = '1'
    print "after"
    print f
time.sleep(3)
```

I expect to turn off light if it is in on condition and vice-versa

Comment: What is currently happenning when you run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is changing `f` from `1` to `0` and then *immediately changing it back again*, so your code is working, but it switches the light off so quickly again you don't see it.

Change this line

```
if f == '0':
```

to

```
elif f == '0':
```